# Android fetch data from database using arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm fetching data from database using arraylist, but some double values convert into round off values.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getTrackList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TRACK";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> trackList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    trackList.clear();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> track = new HashMap<String, String>();
            track.put("LATITUDE", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LATITUDE")));
            track.put("LONGITUDE", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LONGITUDE")));
            track.put("DATE", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DATE")));
            track.put("SPEED", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SPEED")));
            track.put("ACCURACY", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ACCURACY")));
            track.put("PROVIDER", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PROVIDER")));
            track.put("DISTANCE", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DISTANCE")));

            trackList.add(track);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    jSon = new Gson().toJson(trackList);
    cursor.close();
    return trackList;
}
```

here latitude, longitude and distance are double values, distance is same as database, but latitude or longitude are not same, suppose latitude is 22.8569874 in database but it returns 22.857

Comment: How are you storing the values? How are you displaying the values?

Comment: I'm not displaying, m sending this arraylist to the server,

Comment: You can use **Text** later convert it into double when you are using it in application.

Comment: So this not display or storing problem, I can fetch all values, but some data is round off

Comment: Sending to server involves "displaying" as well e.g. converting to a serialization syntax

Comment: What is your data type for latitude in database?

Comment: While storing, store latitude and longitude as `VARCHAR(255)` a `string`, not a `number`.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation for that is that the dataformat in the database is something like `double`.

And if the query reads it out, it rounds the number to 4 digits.

Try it by changing the value in the database to a `string` and write it like this: `22.8569874`; then, if you need the number for calculating or something, you remove the `"` from the string and convert it to a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (cr.moveToNext()) {
    cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("CardName"));
    Log.e("SOAP ERROR",cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("CardName")));
 }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks